# Writing a loop to change directories in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, directory

I'm working on a program where I have data specifically organized by date within several directories.  I'm trying to pull data from each of the individual directories without overwriting anything nor having to write the directory out (it's long) 31 times (once for each day of the month) so I can compile it monthly.  Is it possible to write a for loop for this? If so, what would be the easiest method?  Thanks!

**For example:**

I want to move from:

```
dir\08JUN\2627N.mat
```

to

```
dir\09JUN\2627N.mat
```

and so forth.

Comment: How did the file reading go?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function together with the `isdir` option to retrieve only the directories within the *dir* folder and loop through these directories, reading the 2627N.mat files.

```
out = dir('dir'); % List of directories and files in your dir directory
isub = [out(:).isdir]; % Retrieving directories indexes
subdirectories = {out(isub).name}'; % Converting indexes into logical vector
subdirectories(ismember(subdirectories,{'.','..'})) = []; % Removing '.' and '..'

% Looping through DDMMM subdirectories
for nsub=1:numel(subdirectories)
    % Loading file into workspace
    load(fullfile(dir,subdirectories{nsub},'2627N.mat'));
end
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot today.  Thanks for the insight!